# UINavigationBar and UINavigationController's navigation bar have different blurs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Im stacking a `UINavigationBar` on top of a `UINavigationController`, but their blurs do not match so it doesn't look right. In the `UITableViewController` that is the root view of the `UINavigationController` and I set

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

in `ViewDidLoad` and it does look closer to the top navigation bar, but not matching. How can I get these navigation bars to match? (The navigation bars Im trying to match is the one with the segmented control and the Settings menu)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`? Or hiding `UINavigationController` when the `UINavigationBar` is stacked on top.

Comment: Yes, that is one of Apples solutions in some source code, but Safari on iPad has the bars matching. Its a solution for now, but when I make the bars to the black style, its pitch black instead of a nice translucent grey. So for now thats the solution until I can figure out how to make them match translucency.